# Owl Carousel - only scrolls 1 tab

Tags: javascript, shopify, owl-carousel

on this site [site link](http://www.iswegway.com) there is a owl carousel within a tab system however only the first tab is able to scroll using buttons, when switching tabs the buttons no longer work, any ideas what causes this or how to fix it?
even if the 2 sliders are in different containers, as you can see the bottom containers arrows will slide the content in the top and then stop working for all others.

well i've tried editing the css classes for the .active although i think its most likely javascript, if it didnt load completely id straight guess that but the autoplay and other files are all working and ive run out of options to think of so if anyone else has had this issue or could point me in a different path to look for a solution that would be really helpfu.

Comment: no its generally for being constructive of which your comment is not. i have added some additional points, over all as you could see everything loads, and appears to work, if i could think of a different path to try i would be doing that however since i do not im looking to see if anyone else might have an idea of where to look and then will i try that. try post constructive feedback, it doesnt need to be an answer just something useful.

Comment: Unable to open the site..is it down ?

Comment: It's working from what I see.

Comment: fixed it a few days later, each of the components were working which is why it was a bit more difficult to figure it out obviously if you can see something like a script not loading its easier to fix but the previous developer mixed a bunch together and while each worked they were conflicting with each element in different parts of the structure.

Answer (score 0):

fixed now. seems the person who originally coded it used a weird mixture of different scripts all together and different structure, so stripped away those and set it to use the one set of attributes.